# My minutes on timer doesn't reset to zero

Tags: javascript

When my minute reach to 60 it continues, how do I reset it to zero or back to zero? Here is the code:

```
var timeStart = 0;
var interval;

window.onload = function() {

    interval = setInterval(function timeReady() {
        var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("timeDisplay");
        var hour = Math.floor(timeStart / 3600);
        var min = Math.floor(timeStart / 60);
        var sec = timeStart - (min * 60);
            if (sec < 10) {
                sec = "0" + sec;
            }
        var timeMsg = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        timeDisplay.innerHTML = timeMsg;
            timeStart++;            
    },1000)


    document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };

};
```

Comment: Use Math.floor((timeStart%3600) / 60); to get minutes and Math.floor(((timeStart%3600) % 60) to get seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have wrong calculation of the minutes. Also I fixed your seconds calculation. Try this:

```
interval = setInterval(function timeReady() {
    var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("timeDisplay");
    var hour = Math.floor(timeStart / 3600);
    var min = Math.floor((timeStart % 3600) / 60);
    var sec = timeStart % 60;
        if (sec < 10) {
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
    var timeMsg = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = timeMsg;
        timeStart++;            
},1000)
```

Comment: good help, but i think there's no problem even if you remove the "% 3600" on the minute instead of (timeStart % 3600) / 60 we can have like this: (timeStart) / 60. is it ok?